# Cosmos DB Querying documents that must have two values for the same field

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Hello a litte bit stuck for now. 
Let's say I have a simple collection (maybe not so well built...) :

```
- id
- user_id
- application_id
- version
- [other fields]
```

I would like to get all the user_id for a specific application_id that must have used two specific versions of the application.

If only request a specific version, this is quite easy

```
select c.user_id from c where c.application_id='123456' and c.version='1.0'
```

But if I simply try to add another version (with a AND operator) the result is empty, and that's normal. 
I tried with JOIN operator but didn't succeed to make it work.

Let also say that my SQL background is old and poor and I don't speak about the Cosmos DB SQL specificities

Comment: Just curious, can you not do something like `select c.user_id from c where c.application_id='123456' and (c.version='1.0' or c.version='2.0')`?

Comment: no because I need to get the user_id that uses version=1.0 and also version=2.0. Cannot be imo OR operator

Comment: @user1523812 Don't get your points. What does that mean `I need to get the user_id that uses version=1.0 and also version=2.0`??  One user id has one version and one application_id in one document,is it true?

Comment: Yes its true. But I want to be able to detect user_id that have used two versions of a specific application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I want to be able to detect user_id that have used two versions of
>   a specific application

Maybe i got your point.You mean your data like below:

[image]

A userid has v1 and v2,B userid has v1. Now you just want to select A because A crosses v1 and v2. I'm afraid this requirement could not be implemented with single query sql. You could refer to below sql:

```
SELECT count(c.version) as count,c.userid FROM c
where (c.version='v1' or c.version='v2')
group by c.userid
```

[image]

So then you could know which userid has crossed v1 and v2 based on the `count =2`. Just loop the result by yourself.